# Full width SVG, rounding errors in Safari

Tags: svg, safari, rounding-error

In the following image, notice the left and right of the pink SVG are black borders:

[image]

Demo: https://codepen.io/mhulse/pen/PoZGEqJ

This happens in Safari when viewing at certain viewport sizes (just resize the browser window to see).

**I do not want the black borders.**

A solution I can think of is to add an inset box shadow, to the parent container, that is the color of the white background (in essence, covering it up).

Solutions I can’t accept:

- Negative `1px` margins on left/right. Overflow is not acceptable as it will cause horizontal scrolling (the real world use case touches the edge of the browser viewport).
- Overflow hidden on parent (the real world use case might require children to be absolutely positioned outside of the container).

Is it possible to force the SVG, in Safari, to always touch edge of container and not have black gaps?

Comment: What about a background <rect/>? [updated codepen](https://codepen.io/_-0-_/pen/LYGReeb) This happens because of antialiasing, that browsers try to avoid on most boxes (elements) by rounding the coords. Certainly Safari has different rules for HTML and SVG elements, and you end up with the HTML element stretched and the svg path shrinked to the nearest pixel coord. Note that even on Firefox at non 100% zoom level you'd have the same behavior. Forcing the whole rendering in the SVG image will force the use of a consistent rounding rule, and thus would avoid that issue.

Comment: Whoa! Your solution looks really promising! Thank you for your reply/help! I am testing now. I will respond here with my results. Thank you!!!!!! I'm still trying to understand why a rect seems to solve this issue (re-re-reading your comment now) You ROCK! Again, I'll be back with my findings so I can give you the green checkmark!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a CSS background, you can use a <rect/> as background inside your svg image directly.

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
.box .box-x-cap {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg class="box-x-cap" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 1600 227">
    <rect width="1600" height="277"/>
    <path d="m0 227v-227h1600v32z" fill="pink"></path>
  </svg>
  <p>This is some content.</p>
</div>
```

The problem here is that most browsers will do their best to avoid antialiasing on DOM elements, and to do so, they'll round the coordinates that should have been floating.
Safari certainly uses a different rule for HTML elements and SVG content, which would produce this discrepancy where in some cases the <svg>'s CSS box will get stretched and the inner <path> will get shrank resulting in the background becoming visible on the edges.

By drawing a <rect> behind the <path>, we keep the whole drawing area under the same rules, and the rounding would stay consistent -> the <rect> and <pat> will stretch or shrink together in the same direction.

Comment: YOU ROCK! Thank you so much!!! This works perfectly. I owe you one! :)